# If $X_n\to X$ in probability, are we able to conclude $\sup_{n\ge m}|X_n-X|\to 0$ in probability?

Tags: probability-theory

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $E$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space
- $X,X_n:\Omega\to E$ be $\mathcal A$-measurable for $n\in\mathbb N$ with $$\left\|X_n-X\right\|_E\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\;\;\;\text{in probability}\tag1$$ and $$Z_m:=\sup_{n\ge m}\left\|X_n-X\right\|_E\;\;\;\text{for }m\in\mathbb N$$

> Are we able to conclude $$Z_m\xrightarrow{m\to\infty}0\;\;\;\text{in probability}\tag2?$$

If $\rho,\varepsilon>0$, then by $(1)$ there is a $N\in\mathbb N$ with $$\operatorname P[\left\|X_n-X\right\|_E>\rho]<\varepsilon\;\;\;\text{for all }n\ge N\tag3,$$ but since $$\left\{Z_m>\rho\right\}=\left\{\exists m\ge n:\left\|X_n-X\right\|_E>\rho\right\}=\bigcup_{n\ge m}\left\{\left\|X_n-X\right\|_E>\rho\right\}\tag4$$ for all $m\in\mathbb N$, I don't know how we can proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let $X_1,\ldots, X_n, \ldots$ be a series of random variables as follows:

For each integer $n$ let $j(n)$ be the largest integer such that $2^{j(n)} \leq n$. Then let $X_n$ be the random variable on $[0,1]$ where $X_n$ is 1 on the interval $[\frac{n}{2^{j(n)+1}},\frac{n+1}{2^{j(n)+1}}]$, and 0 everywhere else.

Then the $X_n$s converge in probability to $X$ where $X$ is 0 everywhere on $[0,1]$.

Can also check that $\sup_{n \geq m} |X_n-X|$ is 1 at least on the interval $[\frac{3}{4},1]$

Comment: Doesn't your $X_n$ even almost surely converge to $0$?

Comment: Not almost surely. For any point $x \in [3/4,1]$ there will be some $m$ such that $X_m=1$.